# Consuming JSON with Jersey 2.3 throws XML exception

Tags: json, jersey, entity, moxy

I'm trying to make Jersey 2.3 + Moxy work with my custom objects. Everything is ok when I'm producing JSON from those objects, but refuses to work when I want to consume them by POST. Code first:

Custom object:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ContentAction extends Action {

    private String contentType;
    private Integer contentLength;

    public ContentAction() {
        setType(ActionType.CONTENT);
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }

    public void setContentType(String contentType) {
        this.contentType = contentType;
    }

    public Integer getContentLength() {
        return contentLength;
    }

    public void setContentLength(Integer contentLength) {
        this.contentLength = contentLength;
    }
}
```

Resource fragment (path is declared on the class):

```
@POST
@Produces(JsonHelper.JSON_UTF8)
public Action saveAction(@QueryParam("action") ContentAction action) throws IOException {
    ActionEntity entity = actionConverter.toEntity(action);
    entity.setBeacon(beaconService.findById(action.getBeacon().getId()));

    return actionConverter.convert(actionService.save(entity));
}
```

API caller (class responsible for sending requests):

```
URI uri = buildUri(path, params);

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

buildUri simply creates URI from address & parameters
The action is converted to JSON as follows: `mapper.writeValueAsString(action)`

And the exception:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.ExtractorException: Error unmarshalling JAXB object of type "class com.kontakt.platform.apicommon.model.ContentAction".
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.JaxbStringReaderProvider$RootElementProvider$1.fromString(JaxbStringReaderProvider.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractParamValueExtractor.convert(AbstractParamValueExtractor.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractParamValueExtractor.fromString(AbstractParamValueExtractor.java:129)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.SingleValueExtractor.extract(SingleValueExtractor.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.QueryParamValueFactoryProvider$QueryParamValueFactory.provide(QueryParamValueFactoryProvider.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:353)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:343)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:983)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:359)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:512)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:175)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:140)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.JaxbStringReaderProvider$RootElementProvider$1.fromString(JaxbStringReaderProvider.java:190)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1388)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:998)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:203)
    ... 44 more
```

When I remove @XmlRootElement, Jersey tries to create object from constructor with string parameter (if added) = no automatic bean creation.

I've been stuck with this for two days and I'd be very grateful for any help.

Comment: What does `JsonHelper.JSON_UTF8` correspond to?  In your current config based on the exception the JAXB reference implementation is being leveraged not MOXy, and it is trying to process the input as XML.

Comment: How does the query parameter `action` look like? Are you sending an XML there?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you need to set the content type. Since you are not specifying the content type, jersey is assuming it is reciving xml but it is in fact json. The error message is from jaxb trying to read the xml header and finding invalid characters. Try using the jersey client instead of an http post. Also I think you might what to change your @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) for consistency.

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

**Example POST CODE**

The most important part is that I am setting the type (type(MediaType.Application_JSON) that I am going to post.

```
WebResource webResource = createRestClient(true).resource(
             REST_BASE_PATH + "/service");

ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(ClientResponse.class, contentActionObject);

Assert.assertTrue(response.getStatus() == 200);
```

If you do need to use the HttpPost object then there should be a configuration option to set http headers. I have done this using the the HttpUrlConnection. You would have to set your content type to be application/json instead of xml.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(requestUrl).openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
```

Comment: I've changed my client implementation on the one using Jersey (I used 2.3.1 api, not the 1.x which you've shown) and unfortunately it didn't help. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: The error message you are getting is because Jersey is receiving json and is expecting xml.The SAXParse exception is caused when it is trying to read the <?xml version="1.0"?> header. Did you try changing the @Consumes to use @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)?  And verify that you are setting the post to use the same  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON constant. What does JsonHelper.JSON_UTF8 resolve to be? If it is not "application/json" then you will probably have problems.

Answer (score 0):

[**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) will be picked up as the JSON-binding provder by Jersey for media types that follow the following pattern.

- */json (i.e. application/json and text/json)
- */*+json

Based on your exception it appears as though the media type have have represented with `JsonHelper.JSON_UTF8` does not match this pattern.

Comment: The JsonHelper.JSON_UTF8 is set only for producing which I don't have problem with. However, the JSON_UTF8 is matching the pattern - it's MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON with addres utf-8 at the end

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but I have been encountering the essentially the identical issue using Jersey 2.3 + Moxy. Same scenario and the identical exception is occurring. The only difference is that my POST method is annotated with:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

I did find that when if I passed the same JSON representation in the request body instead of as a query parameter that it was unmarshalled successfully. This would require changing your POST method declaration to:

```
public Action saveAction(ContentAction action)
```

Not sure if this would be a work around for you. If you found a resolution I would be interested in hearing what it was.